# Improving debugger display of my objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, debugging

My google-fu appears to be failing me. I have a fairly basic class that is almost always found in a listof or dictionaryof. I'd like to improve my ability to debug by making the debugger output the contents of the objects instead of:

key, namespace+classname

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730838(v=vs.80).aspx) article, but is there no way to do this in code in the class? I thought all I had to do was write a ToString, but that does not appear to work.

Comment: You might want to show the related code and which form of "debugger output" you mean because *overriding* `.ToString()` works fine with both a List and Dictionary

Comment: Indeed it does. The key is to ensure you put in `overrides` in spite of the compiler not complaining... interesting.

Comment: Without it, the IDE should warn that `ToString shadows an overridable method  in the base class. To override the base method, this method must be declared 'Overrides'.`

Comment: I believe it was, and it was being suppressed somehow. Working fine now though.